# What items in Fallout 4 are level-dependent besides the X-01?

Tags: fallout-4

I recently found out that the X-01 power armor is level-dependent by visiting the same area with a level 30 and a level 20 character and not finding it with the level 20. What other items in the Wasteland are level-dependent?

Comment: I don't have a good list, but a whole lot of the various loot chests/areas are related to level.  Often you will get the same type of gun, but with different mods depending on the level for a given chest.

Answer (score 4):

Basically everything.

Almost every type of equipment loot you encounter will be related to your level, since Fallout 4 is based on the Skyrim engine.  Although there are specific static placements, almost everything else are randomized and based on your level.

Comment: One particular category of note: Armor. You'll mostly see the same general categories of Armor throughout the game, but eventually you'll start climbing up the quality latter from regular to Sturdy and finally Heavy.